# Set specific number of columns for top level term on product category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I’m trying to make category page to show 7 columns , but it modifies subcategories too. Is there any way to modify only the main category page without applying it to subcategories?
https://www.prospecs.lt/?post_type=product

my code :

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 7; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your code, the main filter argument is missing for your function. Now you can use the following to define the main product category loop columns:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'main_product_category_loop_columns', 999);
function main_product_category_loop_columns( $columns ) {
    if( ! is_product_category() )
        return $columns;

    $term = get_queried_object();

    if( $term && is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ) {
        return $term->parent > 0 ? $columns : 7;
    }
    return $columns;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear with my chaotic text. 
What i meant is that, it did not fix my problem. Now the main category which i wanted to modify ONLY restored to the default . What is strange that it modified ONLY the first subcategory while others are untouched.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the condition and separated the templates for the category and subcategory page.

```
$cat = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($cat as $categoria) {
   if($categoria->parent == 0){
     // Use here parent categories template
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it the current page is a `subcategory` with this function.

```
function is_subcategory($cat_id = null) {
    if (is_tax('product_cat')) {

        if (empty($cat_id)){
            $cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
        }

        $cat = get_term(get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat');
        if ( empty($cat->parent) ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then use it in your if statement

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
if (!function_exists('loop_columns') && !is_subcategory()) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: with this it still modifies all of them